# Removing time data point if too close to previous data point

Tags: r

I have a dataset with the following time series:

```
20-05-2017 06:14:24 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:41:13 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:41:14 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:42:13 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:42:14 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:42:20 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:42:36 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:43:05 +00:00
```

What I would like to do is remove the datapoints if there is already one recorded within that same minute, hour or day. To obtain this result (just first data point needed, not averages):

```
20-05-2017 06:14:24 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:41:13 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:42:13 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:43:05 +00:00
```

Any ideas on how to perform this in R? I initially thought about looping a statement that checks every record but since it is a large dataset I don't know whether this would be efficient.

Comment: Are all the datetimes the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a new variable which will include date and hour/minute. In this case, I have converted it to a POSIXlt type and extracted the relevant fields. Using `duplicated` I excluded anything that appears more than once in the dataset.

```
xy <- read.table(text = "20-05-2017 06:14:24 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:41:13 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:41:14 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:42:13 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:42:14 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:42:20 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:42:36 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:43:05 +00:00", header = FALSE)
xy

xy$datetime <- paste(xy$V1, xy$V2)
xy$datetime <- as.POSIXlt(xy$datetime, format = c("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
xy$to_hm <- format(xy$datetime, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
xy[!duplicated(xy$to_hm), ]

          V1       V2     V3            datetime            to_hm
1 20-05-2017 06:14:24 +00:00 2017-05-20 06:14:24 20-05-2017 06:14
2 20-05-2017 07:41:13 +00:00 2017-05-20 07:41:13 20-05-2017 07:41
4 20-05-2017 07:42:13 +00:00 2017-05-20 07:42:13 20-05-2017 07:42
8 20-05-2017 07:43:05 +00:00 2017-05-20 07:43:05 20-05-2017 07:43
```

Comment: This works, thanks!

I didn't initially think about just removing the seconds and removing duplicates in the result.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand...

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
data<-data.table(read.table(col.names = "time1",  text = "20-05-2017 06:14:24 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:41:13 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:41:14 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:42:13 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:42:14 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:42:20 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:42:36 +00:00
20-05-2017 07:43:05 +00:00",sep=","))

data[,time:=dmy_hms(time1)]
data[,time_trunc:=floor_date(time,"minutes")]
data[,time_rank_inside_minute:=frank(time,ties.method = "random"),by=time_trunc]
data<-data[time_rank_inside_minute==1]
```

Comment: Readability could be improved by introducing some spaces in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
require('lubridate')
require('tibble')
require('quantmod')

dfm <- tibble(index = dmy_hms(c('20-05-2017 06:14:24 +00:00', '20-05-2017 07:41:13 +00:00', '20-05-2017 07:41:14 +00:00', '20-05-2017 07:42:13 +00:00', '20-05-2017 07:42:14 +00:00', '20-05-2017 07:42:20 +00:00', '20-05-2017 07:42:36 +00:00', '20-05-2017 07:43:05 +00:00')))

> dfm %>% mutate(index = round_date(index, 'minute'))
# A tibble: 8 x 1
  index              
  <dttm>             
1 2017-05-20 06:14:00
2 2017-05-20 07:41:00
3 2017-05-20 07:41:00
4 2017-05-20 07:42:00
5 2017-05-20 07:42:00
6 2017-05-20 07:42:00
7 2017-05-20 07:43:00
8 2017-05-20 07:43:00
> dfm %>% mutate(index = round_date(index, 'minute')) %>% unique
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  index              
  <dttm>             
1 2017-05-20 06:14:00
2 2017-05-20 07:41:00
3 2017-05-20 07:42:00
4 2017-05-20 07:43:00
```